# how/when do contents of "pages" field get shown for some bibliographic entries?

Tags: cross-referencing

I have some bibliographic items where the number of pages is not available. How to fix this please, here are the references on which I have problem I use googlescholar to determine the bibtex (APA) 
for this paper **1** there is only `pages = {184}`, but the paper is published on a volume I guess we need {start-end} pages. Something like this `pages = {184-257}` basically I have learned the paper **1** from here [link](https://ccforum.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/cc1021) but on my thesis I have to put starting and ending pages I read exactly:

> **1** Chambrin, M.-C. (2001). Alarms in the intensive care unit: how can the number of false alarms be reduced? Critical Care, 5(4), 184

%*** no page here here is the bibtex of this paper :

```
@article{chambrin2001alarms,
 title={Alarms in the intensive care unit: how can the number of false 
 alarms be reduced?},
 author={Chambrin, Marie-Christine},
 journal={Critical Care},
 volume={5},
 number={4},
 pages={184},
 year={2001},
 publisher={BioMed Central}
 }
```

Always in the context of references problem I have this paper here is the bibtex 
entry but number of pages did not appreared on my references although it exists

```
@book{cornuejols2011apprentissage,
title={Apprentissage artificiel: concepts et algorithmes},
author={Cornu{\'e}jols, Antoine and Miclet, Laurent},
year={2011},
**pages={279--309},**
publisher={Editions Eyrolles}
}
```

here is what I get

> Cornuejols, A., & Miclet, L. (2011). Apprentissage artificiel: concepts et algorithmes.Editions Eyrolles.

`pages={279--309}` **even if there is pages :( !! knowing that it works fine for some other references**

also same problem in these references no pages are showed:

```
@book{friedman2001elements,
title={The elements of statistical learning},
author={Friedman, Jerome and Hastie, Trevor and Tibshirani, Robert},
volume={1},
**pages={417--451},**
year={2001},
 publisher={Springer series in statistics Springer, Berlin}
}
```

could this be because it is a book#

here is what I get:

> Friedman, J., Hastie, T., & Tibshirani, R. (2001). The elements of statistical
>   learning (Vol. 1). Springer series in statistics Springer, Berlin

I have also this book the number of pages does not appear.

```
@book{knuth1998art,
 title={The art of computer programming: sorting and searching},
 author={Knuth, Donald Ervin},
 volume={3},
 pages={780},
 year={1998},
 publisher={Pearson Education}
 }
```

same problem here no pages

> **2/** Grossman, D., & Domingos, P. (2004). Learning bayesian network classifiers by maximizing conditional likelihood. In Proceedings of the twenty-first
>   international conference on machine learning.
>
> **3**Cornu´ejols, A., & Miclet, L. (2011). Apprentissage artificiel: concepts et algorithmes. Editions Eyrolles.

Comment: Can you tell us what bibliography style your are using? And what packages you use to produce the bibliography. Many styles I know do not output page numbers for `@book`s. And for the `@article` you just have to research the end page, right? If you have read the paper, that should not be too hard to find out. (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC137277/)

Comment: BTW Your question is quite hard to read. The exclamation marks and the bold do not really help the flow.

Comment: @moewe thank you for edition and your time & consideration basically am new on latex so for the (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC137277/) I read it from there but I have to give the pages on which it has initially published not this page web ! for bib style `\bibliographystyle{Apacite}` for " And what packages you use to produce the bibliography." !! where could I found this information (as I said am new on latex and the main file is very huge (it is a template that I have to use don't really know this info lot of lines of code and don't know the exctly answer for your question

Comment: If some piece of information (here: the final page number in the `pages` field) isn't contained in the bibliographic entry, there's absolutely nothing the software (here: the `apacite` bibliography style and package) can do about it. The only solution is for you to find out what the missing piece of information is and, to edit the bib entry, and to rerun bibtex.

Comment: it is okey for https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC137277/ thank you for all of you but the rest even if I add number of pages it does not appear (@book) Knuth, D. E. (1998). The art of computer programming: sorting and searching
(Vol. 3). Pearson Education. I have added pages={780--781} does not work :($

Comment: `@book{knuth1998art,
  title={The art of computer programming: sorting and searching},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin},
  volume={3},
  pages={780-781},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Pearson Education}
}`

Comment: @mirette - Please be more specific than "does not work". After editing the bib file, did you rerun LaTeX, then BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more?

Comment: yes, I mean I get this "Knuth, D. E. (1998). The art of computer programming: sorting and searching
(Vol. 3). Pearson Education."  no pages ! I do like this "f1,f12, rapid compilation(more than once), then view pdf"

Comment: The standard is that `@book` entries do not get page numbers in the bibliography. If you want to refer to a specific page in the citation, use `\cite[12-13]{foo}`. If you really only want wa particular portion of the book in your references use `@inbook`. See also https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management. You may want to read a good introduction to LaTeX and BibTeX before you proceed.

Comment: @moewe thank you okey I will try  `\cite[12-13]{foo}` just a question in this case I keep  `@book`{... nothing to change hear I delete pages !! no } and when I cite it  I just use \cite[page start-end] {knuth1998art} is not it !!  thank you a lot yeah sure am going to read more but now am in an urgent need to make it work  since I have to finish my thesis in time  :| thank you for help I will try don't go away ;) maybee I need you assistance ^^ ;)

Comment: Most styles simply ignore the `pages` field for `@book`s, so it does not mater if you have it or not (of course it would be better not to have, so you don't trick yourself into thinking it will be displayed). Unfortunately, I don't understand the other points you make in your comment.

Comment: unfortunately here what I get:                                         Cornuejols, A., & Miclet, L. (2011). Apprentissage artificiel: concepts et algorithmes.
Editions Eyrolles.  I used this `\cite[279-309]{cornuejols2011apprentissage}.` my bib contain this  `@book{cornuejols2011apprentissage,
  title={Apprentissage artificiel: concepts et algorithmes},
  author={Cornu{\'e}jols, Antoine and Miclet, Laurent},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Editions Eyrolles}
}`

Comment: @moewe I have tried this `@inbook{cornuejols2011apprentissage,
  title={Apprentissage artificiel: concepts et algorithmes},
  author={Cornu{\'e}jols, Antoine and Miclet, Laurent},
  year={2011},
  pages={1--7},
  publisher={Editions Eyrolles}
}` thank you  for your effort :)

Comment: @moewe you could publish your suggestion  it works :) with  `@inbook ` maybe it helps someone else  just as the code I past in my last comment

Comment: I've taken the liberty to editing the title of your posting, to (hopefully) make the objective of your query more readily apparent. Feel free to revert if you disagree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some general comments, which are predicated on the assumption that you're using BibTeX and the `apacite` citation management package.

- The formatting of the bibliographic entries is determined by the bibliography style that's in use. That would be the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` directive. I take it that you're using the `apacite` bibliography style. (Generally, users of the `apacite` bibliography style utilize the `apacite` citation management package, and vice versa.)
- For entries of type `@book`, the field `pages` is not used all that often. If it's in use at all, it generally contains just one number, viz., the *total number* of pages in the book. It is not at all common to actually typeset this piece of information. (Aside: Who on earth cares about how many pages a book has? You neither, right? Maybe some bibliophiles? You may rest assured that they're not likely to be among the readers of your publication.) As you've discovered, the `apacite` bibliography style is *not* programmed to show the value of the `pages` field for entries of type `@book`, *even if the `pages` field happens to be non-empty*.
- If the bibliographic entry is not about an entire book but about a chapter within a book, one should use the entry type `@inproceedings`, not `@book`. The following code shows such an example.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@inproceedings{cornuejols2011apprentissage,
  title    = {L'Apprentissage de mod{\`e}les lin{\'e}aires},
  booktitle= {Apprentissage artificiel: Concepts et algorithmes},
  author   = {Cornu{\'e}jols, Antoine and Miclet, Laurent},
  year     = 2010,
  edition  = 2,
  chapter  = 9,
  pages    = {299--324},
  publisher= {{\'E}ditions Eyrolles},
  address  = {Paris},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage[english]{babel} % is this right?
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\cite{cornuejols2011apprentissage}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: am definetly gratefull, I think this  would help a lot  me  of course and  good ansewer for those have same problm thank you (y) :)

Comment: Would this be better as `@incollection` with an editor field as well? I find that I never use the `@inproceedings` type at all, since most proceedings are themselves edited volumes.

Comment: @AlanMunn - In the `apacite` bibliography style, `@inbook` and `@inproceedings` are aliases for `@incollection`. :-) No functional difference...